# How to scrape all the posts from a subreddit from a specific period of time?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, reddit, praw

I'm trying to retrieve all the posts from a subreddit that were created in 2020-2021.

Below is the code I wrote to try to solve this

```
import datetime

subreddit = reddit_read_only.subreddit("SuicideWatch")

# Scraping the top posts of all time
posts = subreddit.top("all")
 
posts_dict = {"Title": [], "Post Text": [],
              "ID": [], "Score": [],
              "Total Comments": [], "Post URL": []
              }

start_date = '01-01-20 00:00:00'
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S').timestamp()

end_date = '31-12-21 12:00:00'
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S').timestamp()


for post in posts:
    # Date of each posts' creation
    date = post.created
    if start_date < date < end_date:
        # Title of each post
        posts_dict["Title"].append(post.title)
     
        # Text inside a post
        posts_dict["Post Text"].append(post.selftext)
     
        # Unique ID of each post
        posts_dict["ID"].append(post.id)
     
        # The score of a post
        posts_dict["Score"].append(post.score)
     
        # Total number of comments inside the post
        posts_dict["Total Comments"].append(post.num_comments)
     
        # URL of each post
        posts_dict["Post URL"].append(post.url)
 
# Saving the data in a pandas dataframe
top_posts = pd.DataFrame(posts_dict)
top_posts
```

This worked however, it only returned 72 posts.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988619/praw-6-get-all-submission-of-a-subreddit/54046328#54046328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this. Since I wasn't able to search for posts between a set of dates. I just looked for posts after my start date so that date > start_date.

I also modified one line to set the limit as None so it returned over the default limit of 100 posts.

```
posts = subreddit.top(time_filter = "all", limit = None)
```

This resulted in scraping 764 posts instead of just 72.

Afterwards I altered the "Created On" column into a date using the following:

```
all_posts['Created On'] = pd.to_datetime(all_posts['Created On'],  unit='s')
```

Then I was able to filter for posts created in 2020-2021.

Full Code Below:

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import datetime

subreddit = reddit_read_only.subreddit("SuicideWatch")

# Scraping the top posts of all time
posts = subreddit.top(time_filter = "all", limit = None)
 
posts_dict = {"Title": [], "Post Text": [],
              "ID": [], "Score": [], "Upvote Ratio": [],
              "Total Comments": [],"Created On":[], "Post URL": [],
              "Original Content": []
              }

start_date = '01-01-20 00:00:00'
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S').timestamp()

for post in posts:
    # Date of each posts' creation
    date = post.created_utc
    if date > start_date:
        # Title of each post
        posts_dict["Title"].append(post.title)
     
        # Text inside a post
        posts_dict["Post Text"].append(post.selftext)
     
        # Unique ID of each post
        posts_dict["ID"].append(post.id)
     
        # The score of a post
        posts_dict["Score"].append(post.score)
        
        # Upvote Ratio of a post
        posts_dict["Upvote Ratio"].append(post.upvote_ratio)
     
        # Total number of comments inside the post
        posts_dict["Total Comments"].append(post.num_comments)
         
        # Date the post was Created
        posts_dict["Created On"].append(post.created_utc)
        
        # URL of each post
        posts_dict["Post URL"].append(post.url)
        
        # Flair of each post
        posts_dict["Original Content"].append(post.is_original_content)
        
# Saving the data in a pandas dataframe
all_posts = pd.DataFrame(posts_dict)
all_posts['Created On'] = pd.to_datetime(all_posts['Created On'],  unit='s')
all_posts
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to use PRAW to retrieve posts between two dates. This functionality was removed from version 6.0.0. ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/1126))

> This feature was removed from Reddit's API, and so it was removed from PRAW in version 6.0.0. If you want this functionality, you may be interested in pushshift.io, which is unaffiliated with PRAW.